# Angular 2 Template Parse Error on html5 data- attributes

Tags: angular

The Angular 2 app I'm working on is for a call center.

I have created an Angular 2 component that is a bootstrap modal. It works perfectly when I instantiate one or several on a page, and create the triggers to open them. There are no issues there. I have tested that part thoroughly.

Now in my app, we have a list of checkboxes which when clicked, a modal is supposed to pop up and have instructions for the call center agent to cover when they have chosen a reason for the call.

To create these modals and the triggers, this is the code that I have placed:

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="#case of caseTypes; #i = index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal-i">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="case.selected"> {{case.title}}
    </label>
    <instructions-modal [instruction]="case.instructions" title="{{case.title}}" closeButtonTitle="Finished" modalId="modal-{{i}}"></instructions-modal>
</div>
```

This seems like it should work, but I get the following error in my browser console when I go to the page:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data-toggle' since it isn't a known native property ("ss="col-md-6">
        <h4>Case Type</h4>
        <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="#case of caseTypes; #i = index" [ERROR ->][data-toggle]="modal" [data-target]="modal-i">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cas"): CaseCreation@8:64
Can't bind to 'data-target' since it isn't a known native property ("ase Type</h4>
        <div class="checkbox" *ngFor="#case of caseTypes; #i = index" [data-toggle]="modal" [ERROR ->][data-target]="modal-i">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="case.selected"> {{case.ti"): CaseCreation@8:86
```

I checked [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/3sjnw4/help_cant_bind_to_type_since_it_isnt_a_known/) but it didn't help me any. I tried with and without the `[]` around `data-toggle` and `data-target` and neither way seems to work. I've also tried it on the div that wraps the checkbox as well as the label and I get the same error in both spots.

Is there any way to use `*ngFor` with custom attributes or non-native attributes on HTML elements?

Comment: it is interesting that you get an error, it means that angular actually tries to bind to data-toggle, but it should not do this. Which version of angular do you use? Is your sample code correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `data-` is not a prop (property) of `div`

> `[foo]="exp"` means **"propagate value of exp evaluation to the foo property"**.
>
> If you want to influence attribute value you need to use **`[attr.foo]`**.

This will get it working for you:

```
    [attr.data-toggle]=""
```

Comment: Should this really be necessary? Why are data attributes unique and angular is trying to bind them?

Comment: Without attr. It thinks it's a prop, believe that's why it errors out for them

Comment: So you can't write pure html with angular loaded? It just seems awkward.

Comment: You can, i can't see exactly what he is doing just know that whatever he put, angular thinks it's an actual property of a div tag. Big diff between attr and prop. Going to make a fiddle tomorrow this might be worth making an issue on github over it is rather strange. It is because it's inside an *ngFor as well. But still, weird. @mariocatch

Comment: Also it's because he is doing [ ] brackets around them, all while in a ngFor. I'll look more tomorrow

Comment: It's worth to mention that whatever JS data you're going to attach to these custom properties, if you're grabbing it from an object, you shouldn't use the curly braces (**{}**) to render it.
So, do **NOT** do:
`[attr.data-custom]="{{myObj.property}}"`
Instead, do:
`[attr.data-custom]="myObj.property"`

Answer (score 2):

Angular makes a clear distinction between attribute and properties of an HTML element because they really are.

If you go through the developer guide for [template binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html), it has a section dedicated to this difference.

> Attributes are defined by HTML. Properties are defined by the DOM
> (Document Object Model).

The standard binding operator we use `[]` does a DOM level property binding. To do attribute binding we need a prefix `attr` inside `[]`.

Look at the section `HTML attribute vs. DOM property` to understand how attribtue and property bindings differ.