# Html5 data attributes in div tag ( Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, custom-data-attribute

I am using a theme that i bout on themeforest for my rails project where developers used custom data tags to load background image.Code looks like below.

`<div class="swiper-slide fit slide-1" data-pages-bg-image="assets/images/banner_1.jpg">`

whats the syntax to use data attribute inside div tag? i am using erb as my template engine

Answer (score 2):

## try this patterns

#### 1. using plain html tag

```
<div class="swiper-slide fit slide-1" data-pages-bg-image="assets/images/banner_1.jpg">
```

#### 2. using `content_tag`

*if your ruby version greater than 2.3*

```
<%= content_tag(:div, "blah blah", 'data-pages-bg-image' => "asets/images/banner_1.jpg", class: "swiper-slide fit slide-1") %>
```

*or not (1.9 etc)*

```
<%= content_tag(:div, 'blah blah', "data-pages-bg-image" => "assets/images/banner_1.jpg" :class => "swiper-slide fit slide-1") %>
```

---

example)

```
<section id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "text", :href=> "#", :data => { :flights => "6" } ) %></li>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "text", :href=> "#", :data => { :flights => "5" } ) %></li>
    <li><%= content_tag(:a, "text", :href=> "#", :data => { :flights => "5" } ) %></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set data attributes to your div in your erb with some value from your database, you can do it like this.

```
<div class="swiper-slide fit slide-1" data-pages-bg-image="<%= @item.bg_image %>">
#@item.bg_image is an example, you should put your variable there
```

Comment: Its not coming from my database its coming from my assets. I tried your code for assets it didn't work :(

Comment: Okay, lets say you have image named 'bg_image.jpg'. You can simply write `images/bg_image.jpg` inside the quotes for data attribute. Should work. Let me know!

Comment: Not working tried including and excluding images path

Comment: These are some errors that i am seeing in my console [Console Error Image](http://s33.postimg.org/vtnxd664f/Screen_Shot_2016_06_05_at_12_11_39_PM.png)

Comment: Oh i kind of figured out whats the problem is, theme authors are adding image through jquery and it has `background-image: url()` with url variable inside. So since rails has its own background image syntax its not working.

So i went and changed it to `asset-url` but still not working

Comment: Let me get this straight. You added the data attribute to your div, but you're concerned it didn't change the background, and that's your question?

Comment: I hope you you got your problem fixed, if yes tell me what was the issue and what you did.

Answer (score -1):

data is not a property if div.

You can use attr.data with div. 
[data-pages-bg-image]=

[Please check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585137/angular-2-template-parse-error-on-html5-data-attributes)